# How to modify CSS properties in one element, while selecting another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I know that title is terribly worded, so hopefully I can explain this clearly.

I am modifying an existing google chrome extension. There is a floating button, defined in a .html file as:

```
.button
{
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:  "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px -1px #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-right: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

On pressing this button, there is the following code in a .js file, which determines what should happen.

```
$(".button")
.fadeIn()
.click(function()
{
    if (color == "black")
    {
        do this
    }else if (color == "orange")
    {
        do that
    }else
    {
        or even this
    }
})
```

My goal is to display a new popup on top of the website with information, given that `color == "orange"`. I can get `do this`, `do that`, and `or even this` to run, but what I would really like is to escape the selection of `.button.`, so I can hide/show another popup on the screen without removing / changing the button.

Is there any way to do this? I've thoroughly exhausted my knowledge of html, css, and js, I'm really just a beginner...

Comment: Given that your popup has the id _popup_, you can show it through $("#popup").show();

Comment: Sorry, but no clue what you are trying to ask here. _“escape the selection of .button”_ - no idea what that could mean, not even remotely.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, if I try to access other CSS elements within that if statement, say .popup, which I've also defined in the html file, I can't. It says that these CSS elements don't exist. As far as I can logically figure the problem out, because I am in $(".button").click(function() etc etc), I cannot select other CSS elements.